# why are my matplotlib plots come out as png's only and not as Matlab figures?

Tags: matplotlib

i use a piece of code to produce figures as i run in Pycharm, e.g.:

```
t=np.arange(1,5)
s=2*t+3
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

they come out as png's - how can i display them as figs (as in Matlab) - whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pycharm, go to `Preferences > Tools > Python Scientific`, and disable `Show plots in tool window` (see screenshot attached). You may need to restart Pycharm after. Plots should appear in a separate, interactive pop-up window next time you plot with Matplotlib (that is, more similar to Matlab). If it doesn't work, check your matplotlib backend with `matplotlib.get_backend()`, and try different ones with `matplotlib.use('<backend_name>')`. You can access backend lists like this:
`matplotlib.rcsetup.interactive_bk`, `matplotlib.rcsetup.non_interactive_bk`,
`matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends`.

[image]